# Show Currency code on ajax cart drawer Shopify

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify, currency, currency-formatting

I'm working on `Shopify`. I want to show currency code with currency symbol price for `example : US$30`. By using `"{{ cart.currency.iso_code }}"` I have displayed currency code on whole store, but its not adding on cart drawer because the data adding on cart drawer through `ajax`.

Is any solution to fix this and how can I pass currency code on cart drawer?

Answer (score 0):

I came looking for an answer and since there was none, I managed to solve it. In Shopify ajax cart, change:

```
{{ cart.currency.iso_code }}
```

to:

```
{% endraw %}{{ cart.currency.iso_code }}{% raw %}
```

Comment: I'm in the middle of a possibly similar issue re the cart.    Can you provide some context pls.   I read your answer as  {% raw %} .... {% endraw %}, but then I see it's the other way around ;-?

Comment: endraw at the beginning to close the previous raw. raw at the end to reopen raw